# Can I use iText to render PDF in my Swing application?

Tags: java, swing, pdf, itext

Can iText render PDF documents in Swing application ? Or do I have to use another library/framework for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iText is for producing PDF files programmatically (e.g. converting from HTML to PDF, or producing PDF reports.)

To view PDF you could use a library like [ICEpdf](http://www.icepdf.org/)

Comment: I am starting to lean away from ICEpdf... we pay for it, but every time so far where a PDF file hasn't rendered correctly, it turns out to be a "new feature", at which point they give a quote for an immense amount of money for a custom fix.  Not a great experience so far... but I guess it works for "most" files.

Comment: I've no experience with ICEpdf, but recently I've used pdf-jet. The free version is fairly low to medium level, but it got the job done for what I needed it for - a simple report. http://pdfjet.com/. Most things have to be specified as co-ordinates, so using a swing layout might make sense for complex layouts. I just computed the co-ords for my use case.

Answer (score 3):

There is also an open source/commercial versions of JPedal and Suns PDFRenderer.