# Converting file formats (PDF to TIFF?)

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, silverlight-4.0, file-conversion

Hi guys an easy one here,

What are some of the better converts out there which work well and what are the drawbacks of doing a conversions if any? Loss of quality/res/anything?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717522/can-i-use-itext-to-render-pdf-in-my-swing-application

Comment: The link you provided is not a .NET solution, it is related to Java and swing...

Answer (score 1):

see here [Convert PDF file to images using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492129)

Only drawback, if it is one, is that you need to install ghostscript.
Also, once in a while gs can't parse a file that adobe can.

Answer (score 1):

There are no open source .net libraries that can do that. Either use ghostscript or imagick ([.net wrapper](http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/)) for the conversion. Ghostscript gives you better quality than imagick.

I believe that [abcpdf](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm) can do [that](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/7298), but it's a commerical component.

Answer (score 1):

There are many products I found that can do this. Some have a cost while some are free.

I used Black Ice http://www.blackice.com/Printer%20Drivers/Tiff%20Printer%20Drivers.htm. This is afordable at about $40. I didn't buy this one though.

I ended up using a free one called MyMorph.