# How to display iText Image object in java

Tags: java, swing, itext

I am creating a PDF reader in java. For reading PDF files i am using iText library. I have a sample code to read the PDF files but i don't know how to display the iText Image object in a JFrame.Below is the code to read a PDF file.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class ReadAndUsePdf {
private static String INPUTFILE = "c:/temp/FirstPdf.pdf";
private static String OUTPUTFILE = "c:/temp/ReadPdf.pdf";

public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException,
        IOException {
    Document document = new Document();

    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
            new FileOutputStream(OUTPUTFILE));
    document.open();
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(INPUTFILE);
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    PdfImportedPage page;
    // Go through all pages
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        // Only page number 2 will be included
        if (i == 2) {
            page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
            Image instance = Image.getInstance(page); //how to show this object in a JFrame
            document.add(instance);
        }
    }
    document.close();

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the exactly same problem, and I solved it by using [ICEPdf](http://www.icesoft.org/projects/ICEpdf/overview.jsf) to render the PDF in Swing, and iText to manipulate it.

Possible duplication: [Can I use iText to render PDF in my Swing application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717522/can-i-use-itext-to-render-pdf-in-my-swing-application)